# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView: scrolling is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`. What I want is to scroll entire content of `NestedScrollView` if `NestedScrollViews` content (including list passed to `RecyclerViews` adapter) is above certain height.

I have custom `NestedScrollView` class to handle this which is measuring height of all children inside `onMeasure` and if total children height will pass certain value, it should enable scrolling instead of expanding `NestedScrollView` height. (I need this feature because `NestedScrollView` is allowed to be expanded to maximum of 40% of display height).

This feature is working well if I'm filling `NestedScrollView` with generic components containing `RelativeLayouts`, `TextViews`, `Buttons` etc. But `RecyclerView` is completely blocking scrolling of entire `NestedScrollView` for some reason.

Here is logging from `NestedScrollView:`

```
ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: onMeasure curr_height: 11678, max: 966
```

NestedScrollView:

```
class ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: NestedScrollView{
    private var maxHeight = WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    var onHeightChangeListener: ((Int)->Unit)? = null
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        var measuredHeight = heightMeasureSpec
        val currHeight = getCurrContentHeight()
        try {
            val heightSize: Int
            App.log("ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: onMeasure curr_height: $currHeight, max: $maxHeight")
            if (maxHeight != WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE && currHeight > maxHeight) {
                heightSize = maxHeight
            } else {
                heightSize = currHeight
            }
            measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            layoutParams.height = heightSize
            onHeightChangeListener?.invoke(heightSize)
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        } finally {
            App.log("ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: onMeasure final: $measuredHeight")
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, measuredHeight)
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrContentHeight(): Int{
        var height = 0
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            val h = child.measuredHeight
            App.log("ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: getCurrChildHeight: $h")
            if (h > height) height = h
        }

        return height
    }

    fun setOnDynamicHeightChangeListener(l: (Int)->Unit){
        onHeightChangeListener = l
    }

    fun setMaxHeight(maxHeight: Int) {
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight
    }

    companion object {
        var WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE = -1
    }
}
```

RecyclerView init + layout:

```
list = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list).also { rv ->
                rv.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                rv.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> false }
                rv.adapter = adapter
                rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(a)
            }
```

Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
            <components.loading_indicator.LoadingIndicator
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    
        </RelativeLayout>
```

NestedScrollView init:

```
it.findViewById<ScrollViewWithMaxHeight>(R.id.scrollParent).also { sv->
                sv.setMaxHeight(getScrollViewHeight())
                sv.setOnDynamicHeightChangeListener { h-> }
                sv.isFillViewport = true
                sv.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
                    isScrollOnTop = sv.scrollY == 0
                }
            }
```

Here is issue what is causing Scroll lags:

```
2023-03-28 09:48:18.430 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:18.435 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:18.440 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:18.445 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.955 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.962 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.967 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.973 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.979 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.985 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.990 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:27.996 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.002 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.008 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.013 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.019 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.025 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.031 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
2023-03-28 09:48:28.037 I  RecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: creating item
...
```

This is log inside `onCreateViewHolder`. Its called on every single item in list. Even as I try to scroll, its called again. Not sure what is causing this. I have `RecyclerViews` all over my app and only this one is not recycling.

Ok I found it what is causing this. Its really weird. I have another horizontal `RecyclerView` above `NestedScrollView` (which is obviously not part of `NestedScrollView` because its static and its not suppose to scroll vertically. Its just horizontal picker with items in it.

As soon as I removed it from layout, vertical scrolling worked as usual with proper recycling.

My layout design and component design is modular and I inject layout with inflation and `addView` function to parents so I can make standalone components within code which can be injected into any empty layout.
I removed `NestedScrollView` from it because its not necessary to reconstruct the bug. It is happening even if there is only `RecyclerView` as component (so I dont need nested scrolling at all).

As soon as `horizontal_picker_content` is injected there and used, its blocking recycling of `vertical_list_container` which is place where my vertical `RecyclerView` is injected.

So I reconstructed how my final layout would look like in my `DialogBottomSheet` so you can see how it is structured:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomContentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:background="@color/background_paper"
                    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/peekSwiper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/dialog_title_block"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:elevation="0dp"
                            android:translationZ="4dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_bottomsheet_top"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dialog_bottom_block"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@id/peekSwiper"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/dialog_title_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/background_paper"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/horizontal_picker_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:clipToPadding="false"
                                android:clipChildren="false"
                                android:gravity="center">

                                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/horizontalPickList"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                                    android:clipChildren="false"
                                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

                                <include
                                    layout="@layout/menu_item_separator"
                                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalPickList"/>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:clipChildren="false"
                                android:clipToPadding="false"
                                android:background="@color/background_paper">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/vertical_content_parent"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                                    android:clipChildren="false"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:id="@+id/vertical_content_container"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                                        android:clipChildren="false"
                                        android:orientation="vertical">

                                    </LinearLayout>

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/vertical_list_container"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@id/vertical_content_parent"
                                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                                    android:clipChildren="false"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dialog_bottom_block"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) method on the RecyclerView instance?

Comment: yes. Its not working. I even tried to remove NestedScrollView parent and its still not recycling

Comment: `rv.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false` try removing this line and letting the RecyclerView handle the nested scrolling. You can also remove the rv.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> false } line, as it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: rv.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> false } supposed to enable handling of scrolling by NestedScrollView. And same with nested scrolling. You need to handle scrolling by NestedScrollView in case of multiple views inside NestedScrollView.